# How to apply the hyperlink for specific text in uitextfiuled or uilabel

Tags: iphone

i am developing one application.In that i want to use UILabel or UITextField to place the text.But i need to apply the hyperlink for some part of that text.I am searching on internet,no use of search.So please tell me how can i do that one for UILabel or UITextField.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take two different labels, one for "Here" word and another for "is my application". Make userIneraction true for "Here" label. Apply gesture to that label and on touch of that label redirect user to appropriate link.