# UIlabel into a url?

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa, webview

i created a uilabel that contains my location data using this code,

```
longitudedata.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"longitude=%f", location.coordinate.longitude];
speeddata.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"speed=%f", [location speed] * 2.2369];
altitudedata.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"altitude=%f", [location altitude]];
```

but now i need to add these in a url so it will send that data to my server but everything iv tried  dosnt work :(

```
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[@"http://servername/ldtracker.aspx?id=3&" stringByAppendingString:longitudedata.text]];
```

and so on but this dosnt work, seems like iv tried everything

im a beginner to xcode, please help :)

Comment: Chech this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13447827/how-to-apply-the-hyperlink-for-specific-text-in-uitextfiuled-or-uilabel/13449341#13449341

Comment: @AKV with this bit of code, when i run it and turn it on (im using a switch to activate it for other reasons) it just crashes and theres no  clear error.

Comment: You can check the constructed URL by logging it like NSLog(@"url - %@", [myURL absoluteString]). In this way it'll help you to identify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

UILabels dont handle urls, u need to give them a NSString.
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://servername/ldtracker.aspx?id=3&%@", longitudedata.text];

this should work if i understood ur problem correctly

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://servername/ldtracker.aspx?id=3&%@&%@%@",longitudedata.text,speeddata.text,altitudedata.text]];
```

Comment: i had tried this, which seems to work at first, no errors or crashes but dosnt display the data on my database :(

Comment: So the problem is with longitudedata.text not containing the text you need?